# Передача значения при выборе значения

Tags: angularjs

```
<select id="type" name="type" ng-model="model.obj">
    <option value="">Не указано</option>
    <option ng-repeat="obj in objs" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Есть такой код. В каждом obj, кроме id и name, есть еще параметры, поэтому мне нужно передать весь obj в функцию при выборе значения в селекте. Добавить `ng-change="foo(obj)"` - в функцию не будут передаваться obj (undefined), `ng-click` в `option` тоже не срабатывает (просто не происходит ничего). Какое есть событие в angularJS, которое можно привязать к `option`, которое срабатывает при выборе значения? Или какой есть еще способ передать объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В angular существует специальная директива [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) для создания селектов.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
<select id="type" name="type" ng-model="model.obj"
        ng-options="obj.name for obj in objs track by obj.id">
</select>
```

Тогда при любом изменении селекта весь obj целиком окажется в model.obj автоматически. Единственное, на что нужно обратить внимание, - это дефолтное пустое значение. Его прийдется внести в список objs.

Вот вам рабочий пример http://jsfiddle.net/e21cwov1/11/